# VBA Excel - Delete 2 rows above the row with a specific keyword

Tags: excel, vba

I have little insight in VBA, hence I need someone to help me with a script to achieve the outcome as stated in title.

I need to extract specific rows from a log file that I have.

Excerpt from actual log file in excel:

```
=====================================

Encrypted file: C:\[specific path]      
Algorithm picked for decryption: RC4        
Status: Successfully decrypted!     

Encrypted file: C:\[specific path]          
File looks like it is not encrypted. Skipping ...       

Encrypted file: C:\[specific path]      
File could not be decrypted properly. Skipping ...      

=====================================
```

It goes like this for about 90k rows. I need to get rid of all "Status: Successfully decrypted!" rows with 2 rows above it. 
The final data that I need are only rows with skipped paths, that failed decryption.

Each block of text in this log is followed by blank row.

Tried the following one:

Sub DeleteRowsBelow()

```
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Cells.Find(What:="Macro", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Select
y = Selection.Row + 1
Rows(x & ":" & y).EntireRow.Delete
```

End Sub

But it deletes all of the rows below a certain keyword, so that does not work for me.

Then tried to incorporate the following into the above script:

Rows("1:" & Cells.Find("KEY WORD").Row - 1).Delete

But also with little luck, and again it deletes all of the rows above a certain keyword.

Comment: *help me with a script* generally implies that you've done some work so far. Please show what you've tried so far. There is ample documentation on basic I/O functions for reading text files/etc. on the web :)

Comment: Edited the post with attempted scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but maybe it will help

Just select the cell at the top of the list and run the macro

```
Sub DeleteSuccessfulRows()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x
For x = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row To ActiveCell.Row Step -1
    If Cells(x, 1) = "Status: Successfully decrypted!" Then 'If we find this text
        Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete      'Delete the entire row
        Cells(x - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete  'Delete the row above it
        Cells(x - 2, 1).EntireRow.Delete  'Delete the row 2 rows above it
        x = x - 2
    'Delete blank rows
    ElseIf Cells(x, 1) = vbNullString Then Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    'Optional delete rows that contain "File looks like ..."
    'ElseIf Cells(x, 1) = "File looks like it is not encrypted. Skipping ..." Then Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    'ElseIf Cells(x, 1) = "File could not be decrypted properly. Skipping ..." Then Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Results:

[image: After]